# Enabling Different Login Options to Work Concurrently in Apereo CAS

Tags: java, spring, single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I've installed Apereo CAS on a server and have Enabled Normal Login Form and QR Authentication together, Now i want to add Password Less Login to the other two as a third option for users to use when they Login, but CAS Login Page only shows the Password Less Login.

Is there a way to set up all three at the same time and let the user decide which one to use?

I tried editing Template files to show all the options at once, but only Password Less Login seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to set up all three at the same time and let the user decide which one to use?

No. Not without significant changes to the spring webflow to include all options at the same time, the details of which are beyond the scope of this question/answer.